# starting hadoop without error, but can't connect to server

Tags: java, hadoop, ssh

I am starting to use hadoop and was reading a lot of tutorials to understand all the steps to start it for the first time.
I am running a virtual machine downloaded from the yahoo tutorial with hadoop and java pre-installed.

My main problem is:
If I start the `start-all.sh` script (after `hadoop namenode -format`), I don't get any error, but when I try to connect to the filesystem with `hadoop fs ls` I get the following erros:

`14/07/18 04:49:43 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node1/10.10.104.68:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
.....
14/07/18 04:49:52 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node1/10.10.104.68:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).
Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to node1/10.10.104.68:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

While trying to find the solution for this problem I found out the following strange things:

1.) After running `stop-all.sh` It writes:

`no jobtracker to stop
node1: no tasktracker to stop
no namenode to stop
node1: stopping datanode
localhost: stopping secondarynamenode`

2.) netstat does not show anything listening on port 9000, Why?

3.) The webinterface of hadoop (on IP:50070 and :50030) is always running when I try to connect via my 'master' pc (also after stopping), Why?

So, it obviously does not start correct, but I really don't know why...
I have configured and double checked:

- the hosts file
- the ssh configuration
- the properties that I have set in core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml; slaves file has only node1 as entry
- the permissions of all the directories (I also don't use the tmp folder)

Unfortunately I'm not able to install any new packages due to proxy permissions. `jps` does not work (I think the pre-installed java version does not support it !?) and the result of `ps aux | grep java` doesn't make a lot of sense for me.

I would be happy about any idea why it maybe does not work, or any hint that I should try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by going to the logs folder and checking out the logs for the hadoop daemons.  You will see why they are not starting.  There are a bunch of simple reasons why the daemons have trouble starting; can't find JAVA_HOME, can't find HADOOP_HOME, etc.  The logs will point you in the right direction.  There will be a log file for each daemon (namenode, datanode, jobtracker, etc).  I would start with the namenode log first.  If namenode is not happy, nobody is happy.

Make sure everything is installed where you think it is.  And make sure the hadoop shell scripts know how to find these locations.

Comment: it's starting now, I had the problem that a port was already in use (from the log files)... It was no other (useful) program, but a hung up java process. After killing all running java processes, the namenode was starting successful.